# d3.js rotate text in svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm fairly new to d3 but this seems like a fairly simple question that I can't find the answer to. Maybe I'm just missing something fundamental. Anyway, any help is much appreciated.

I've create circles in my svg and I want to label them with text, which I have accomplished, but the text overlaps, so I want to rotate the text 45 degrees (technically 315 degrees). Here is a snippet of my code to attempt this:

```
        var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr ("x",function(d, i) { return (i * 30) + 50;})
            .attr ("y",function(d) { return 250 - (d.some_var * 50);})
            .attr("rotate", 315)
            .text(function(d){ return d.name; });
```

Weirdly though, this rotates each letter in the word instead of rotating the whole word. Screenshot is attached.

[image]

What am I missing here? Thanks for any direction!

Comment: is this you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252753/rotate-x-axis-text-in-d3

Comment: `rotate` as a attribute of `<text>` is different from the `rotate` in the `transform` attribute. Have a look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text): *"This attribute set the orientation of **each** individual glyph."*.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment you are rotating each text element:

```
.attr("rotate", 315)
```

Instead you need to transform the whole text element, so replace the the rotate with the following:

```
.attr('transform', 'rotate(45)')
```

You will need to tweak the values for your needs but it should do the trick.

You can also pass in the x/y coordinates straight into the rotate function to maintain it's placement, i.e.

```
.attr('transform', 'rotate(45 ' + xValue + ' ' + yValue + ')')
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not 100% sure, but that appears to be rotating them relative to the origin. I'd like to rotate them relative to the `attr("x", ..)` and  `attr("y", ..)` that I give them each. I can attach a screen shot if necessary.

Comment: Yea please, could you attach a screenshot with as much detail as you can.

Comment: I think I understand now what you mean. I've updated the answer to include what I think you want.

Comment: I can't get your idea to work in practice @ArnaudStephan, see http://plnkr.co/edit/9pxJLz?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, because your Plunker seems fine to me.

Comment: @ArnaudStephan if you take another look at my plnkr then you can see how adding what I said into the transform function gets the desired result.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Indeed it is, my mistake. I deleted my comment.